# why getting error message while trying to get a file using require

Tags: php, apache

```
<?php
require("C:\htdocs\myportfolio\fpdf\fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->setfont("Arial",'B',16);
$pdf->cell(40,10,"Hello Out There");
$pdf->output();
echo "Hi";

?>
```

Below is the message I get on my browser.
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\myportfolio/../fpdf/fpdf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\myportfolio\Home.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myportfolio/../fpdf/fpdf.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\myportfolio\Home.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php

I hope it helps you how to include the path.